# parametric data instance parametric class haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following haskell code for a real-time queue and i have a parametric data type and a parametric class. When i want to print something i revive this error :

```
interactive>:1:1: error:
* Ambiguous type variables q0',a0' arising from a use of `print'
  prevents the constraint `(Show (q0 a0))' from being solved.      
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `q0',
                                                      `a0' should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance [safe] Show a => Show (Queue a)
      -- Defined at real-timeQueue.hs:1:39
    instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
    instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a, b) -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
    ...plus 14 others
    ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
* In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

```
data Queue a = Queue [a] [a]
               deriving (Show)

class QueueOperations q where
    newQ :: q a
    empty :: q a -> Bool
    push :: q a -> a -> q a 
    pop :: q a -> q a
    front :: q a -> a
    rev :: q a -> q a

instance QueueOperations Queue where
    empty (Queue [] []) = True
    empty _ = False
    newQ = Queue [] []
    push (Queue xs ys) x = Queue xs (x : ys)
    pop (Queue [] ys) = pop (Queue (reverse ys) [])
    pop (Queue (x : xs) ys) = Queue xs ys
    front (Queue [] ys) = front (Queue (reverse ys) [])
    front (Queue (x : xs) ys) = x
    rev (Queue xs ys) = Queue ys xs
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to print? Please post [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If i write `newQ` in terminal it should print `Queue [] []` but i recive that error and same on other operations like
`
q = newQ
push q 3
`

Comment: @AndreiMănăilă No it should not print that -- `newQ` can produce any type supporting `QueueOperations`, not only `Queue a`, so it's ambiguous. Try to disambiguate using e.g. `newQ :: Queue Int`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, this happens because the types are ambiguous. Methods like `newQ` and `push` don't return `Queue a` - they return `q a`. This *could* be `Queue a`, but it might also be some other instance of the `QueueOperations` type class.

Consider, for example, `newQ`:

```
*Q62022672> q = newQ
*Q62022672> :t q
q :: QueueOperations q => q a
```

The type of `q` is *still parametrically polymorphic.* You haven't decided on a particular instance, so GHCi hasn't decided, either.

You can make it unambiguous with a type annotation. In GHCi, it might look like:

```
*Q62022672> q :: Queue a
Queue [] []
```

You have the same problem with the `push` method:

```
*Q62022672> :t push q 3
push q 3 :: (QueueOperations q, Num a) => q a
```

GHCi can fairly well deal with the `Num` ambiguity, but not with the `QueueOperations` ambiguity. It doesn't know how to display (`show`) that.

Again, you can help it with a type annotation:

```
*Q62022672> push q 3 :: Queue Int
Queue [] [3]
```

or, if you want to keep the `a` generic:

```
*Q62022672> push q 3 :: Num a => Queue a
Queue [] [3]
```

This is mostly a problem related to GHCi, because, being a *Read Eval Print Loop*, it wants to print the value of the expression, and it doesn't know how to do that, unless you help it. The type annotations help it *print* the values. You don't need them for the code to type check, though, as demonstrated by the above use of `:t`.